# I have problem with awesome_page_transition package with exitpage

Tags: flutter

I try to use this package for my mobile app. It creates effect for all transition pages. Here is the package link : https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_page_transitions.
The recommanded code is :

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        AwesomePageRoute(
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          exitPage: widget,
          enterPage: SecondScreen(),
          transition: CubeTransition(),
        ),
      ),
```

enterPage is the destination page it is OK. My problem is with exitPage, it says "widget". On one of my page, it works, "widget" is recognized so no errors and all works but on others pages i have an error "undefined name 'widget'".

So my question is what is "widget" and why it is not recognized on some pages.

Here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_app/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:awesome_page_transitions/awesome_page_transitions.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  final appTitle = 'WINACOIN';

  String mail;
  String pass;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'WINACOIN',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          fontFamily: 'Azonix',
        ),
        home: MyHome()
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override

  String mail='';
  String pass='';

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("WINACOIN"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.blue[400],Colors.blue[600],Colors.blue[800]],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight),
          ),
          child :
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin : const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:20),
                  child: Text('JEU 100 % GRATUIT 100 % GAGNANT',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin : const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:20),
                  child: Text('GAGNEZ DES CADEAUX ET DES EUROS',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text('COMMENCER',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    bool islog = await isconnect();
                    if (islog==false) {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                        AwesomePageRoute(
                          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                          exitPage: MyApp(),
                          enterPage: LoginPage(),
                          transition: RotateUpTransition(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    else {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                        AwesomePageRoute(
                          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                          exitPage: MyApp(),
                          enterPage: HomePage(),
                          transition: RotateUpTransition(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }

  Future <bool> isconnect() async {
    // Create storage

    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Read value

    mail = await storage.read(key: "e");
    pass = await storage.read(key: "p");

    if (mail!=null && pass!=null) {

      var url = 'https://www.easytrafic.fr/game_app/login.php';

      // Store all data with Param Name.
      var data = {'email': mail, 'password': pass};

      // Starting Web API Call.
      var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data),headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json'});

      print(json.decode(response.body));
      // Getting Server response into variable.

      Map <String,dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);

      // If the Response Message is Matched.
      if (map["status"] == 1) {
        // l'email et le mot de passe sont correct
        final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

        await storage.write(key: "i", value: map["id_membre"]);
        await storage.write(key: "e", value: mail);
        await storage.write(key: "p", value: pass);
        await storage.write(key: "t", value: map["jwt"]);

        globals.id_membre=map["id_membre"];
        globals.token=map["jwt"];
        globals.balance=double.parse(map["balance"]);
        globals.points=map["nb_points"];
        print("la connexion a réussi avec les identifiants");

        return true;
      }
      else {
        // l'email et mot de passe stocké ne permettent pas de se connecter
        // rediriger vers la fenêtre de login
        print("mauvais identifiants");
        return false;
      }
    }
    else {
      // email et password n'existe pas
      print("email et password vide");
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

I have a little different problem on an other page, it is a class which display a drawer :

Here is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/grille_lotosport.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/liste_grattage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/liste_tombolas.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/liste_grille_lotto.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/liste_pronostics.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/boutique.dart';
import 'package:awesome_page_transitions/awesome_page_transitions.dart';

class DrawerOnly extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            new DrawerHeader(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.userAlt,
                      size: 40,
                      color: Colors.white
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      width: 150,
                      height:35,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 2,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      ),
                    child: Center(
                    child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                    children: [
                    WidgetSpan(
                    child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.euroSign,color: Colors.amber[200],size:20)
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                    text: (globals.balance??0).toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,color: Colors.white)
                    ),
                    ],
                    ),
                    )
                    )
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: 150,
                      height:35,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 2,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              children: [
                                WidgetSpan(
                                    child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidGem,color: Colors.amber[200],size: 20)
                                ),
                                TextSpan(
                                    text: " "+(globals.points??0).toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,color: Colors.white)
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                      )
                  ),
                  ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: <Color>[
                      Colors.blue[400],Colors.blue[600],Colors.blue[800]
                    ],
                  ),
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft:  const  Radius.circular(25.0),
                  bottomRight: const  Radius.circular(25.0)
                  )
              ),
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home),
              title: new Text("ACCUEIL"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(ctxt);
                Navigator.push(ctxt,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new HomePage()));
              },
            ),
            new ExpansionTile(
              leading: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.play),
              title: Text("NOS JEUX"),
              children: <Widget>[
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("LOTOSPORT"),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(ctxt);
                    Navigator.push(ctxt,
                        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new Affiche_Liste_grille()));
                  },
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("PRONOSTICS"),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(ctxt);
                    Navigator.push(ctxt,
                        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new Affiche_Matchs())
                    );
                  }
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("LOTERIE"),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(ctxt);
                    Navigator.push(ctxt,
                        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new Affiche_Liste_Lotto()));
                  },
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("TOMBOLA"),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(ctxt);
                    Navigator.push(ctxt,
                        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new Affiche_Liste_Tombola())
                    );
                  },
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text("TICKET A GRATTER"),
                  onTap:() {
                    Navigator.pop(ctxt);
                    Navigator.push(ctxt,
                        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new Affiche_Liste_Grattage()));
                  }
                )
              ],
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.gift),
              title: new Text("BOUTIQUE"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(ctxt);
                Navigator.push(ctxt,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new Affiche_Boutique()));
              },
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.signOutAlt),
              title: new Text("DECONNEXION"),
              onTap: () async {
                final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

                await storage.deleteAll();

                globals.id_membre="";
                globals.token="";
                globals.balance=0.00;

                Navigator.pop(ctxt);
                Navigator.push(ctxt,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new LoginPage()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

I want to use the same method so :

Navigator.push(
        context,
        AwesomePageRoute(
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          exitPage: widget,
          enterPage: SecondScreen(),
          transition: CubeTransition(),
        ),
      ),
context is ok but exitpage it is the same problem i can't access to it and i can't call the page directly because in this class i don't know on which page we are. Perhaps i need to pass this information to this class each times but how ???
For the moment, i call this like that : drawer: new DrawerOnly(), on each page, i can pass the widget information ? If yes, how ?
Thanks``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case where it is working for i think it is stateful widget, when widget act as your class name.

Example, If your stateful widget is FirstApp then it will reference it if you pass widget. As we access variable's when we are getting from other class.

In StateFul Widget case:

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}
```

In state

```
AwesomePageRoute(
            transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
            exitPage: widget,  //  exitPage: DeleteWidget(), both will work

            enterPage: SecondScreen(),
            transition: CubeTransition(),
          ),
```

Now, where is is giving error is your stless widget because of that widget is not available. To solve your issue, you can assign your class name instead of Widget.

In stateless Widget.

```
  class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
```

You have to provide in following way.

```
    AwesomePageRoute(
            transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
            exitPage: SecondScreen(),  // because in stless their in now widget
            enterPage: DeleteWidget(),
            transition: CubeTransition(),
          ),
```

Update:

You have to assign drawer(DrawerOnly) in any class(stateful/stateless widget) in drawer property of scaffold, then you can pass that class name, and assign that value to exitPage.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: CustomDrawer(
        className: DeleteWidget(),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("hello"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget className;
  CustomDrawer({this.className});
  @override
  _CustomDrawerState createState() => _CustomDrawerState();
}

class _CustomDrawerState extends State<CustomDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          new ListTile(
            leading: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text("ACCUEIL"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  AwesomePageRoute(
                    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                    exitPage: widget.className,
                    enterPage: HomePage(),
                    transition: CubeTransition(),
                  ));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text("HomePage"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it acts like you are providing class. @GenchiGenbutsu i updated my answer, now it make more sense.

Comment: create_state() need to be Always in mobile app page ??? I have seen there is not in my main.dart i have add it but problems is Always there i can't access to widget, strange

Comment: Create state reffer to state of widget not app. Files could be anywhere in code, it doesn't matter.

Comment: i have updated the code. Can you Watch it please ? I have changed the code with your recommendations. But my question is what is exactly exitpage ??? Because enterPage is the destination page so i think exitpage is the origin page ??? Do you confirm ?

Comment: i have too add a little other problem at the Bottom of my comment for use the same system in a drawer but which is in separated dart file in a class i called on each page

Comment: i search for a while, but because of lack if documentation i can'r say surely what is actual use. but i experiment and i found that if you assign any other class(screen/widget) then it will call it's init state, while pushing new screen and call it's dispose method, while we call pop in new screen.

Comment: i think of you don't pass any argument then also it will wok fine.

Comment: the problem is i need use : AwesomePageRoute(
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          exitPage: widget,
          enterPage: SecondScreen(),
          transition: CubeTransition(),
        ), and i Don't see how i can pass the widget in this class which is apart in a .dart file

Comment: 1000 Thanks for you it works great now :) You are my savior :) What do you think about transition time for transitionpage, before  have set 1000 ms, you set 600 ms it seems

Comment: It was just for testing for me!